# Do all attacks against PKCS1 v1.5 encryption require an oracle

Tags: rsa

As far as I know, all attacks against RSA PKCS1 v1.5 require an oracle; is that true? Or are there any other attacks against it which are able to break it without an oracle?

Background: I need to support PKCS1 v1.5 because most crypto-devices sadly don't support OAEP. However, the software is only used for manual file en-/decryption, so there is not an oracle available.

Comment: Damn, I think your'e right; I actually forgot about that forum...

Comment: You're welcome, K. Biermann. We're still migrating out of beta, but we're up and running for sure. Always keep side channel attacks in mind when talking RSA - but that goes as much for OAEP as for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: Very much related, older article on the security site: [What specific padding weakness does OAEP address in RSA?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32050/what-specific-padding-weakness-does-oaep-address-in-rsa). Note that the padding oracle attack is known as "Bleichenbacher's attack".

Comment: Do we generally assume 02 (random) padding? Or can we also assume 00 (zero) or 01 (0xFF) padding? [RFC2313](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2313)

Comment: Yes, the cards and the software-lib I use (OpenSSL) both do random padding.

Comment: To be very precise that would be RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 that uses EME-PKCS1-v1_5 encoding, according to PKCS#1 v2.1 specifications. Not used much, but it doesn't leave any doubts to what scheme is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PKCS#1 padding succeeds in introducing enough entropy (slightly less than 64 bits at the very minimum) to make RSA encryption semantically secure. Furthermore, the number $m$ - the message used for modular exponentiation - it produces will be large enough to protect against attacks that rely on $m$ to be small. That means that the premisses for RSA modular exponentiation seem to be met.

It seems therefore unlikely that there are *passive* attacks on PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. Active attacks could succeed, as Bleichenbacher has shown. It may be that there are attacks on the random number generation as well, but that will require an attacker to have even higher privileges; the attacker must have access to the secure random number generator used. Usually those kind of attacks are considered attacks on the secure system creating the ciphertext itself instead of attacks on the algorithm itself.

Finally there are side channel attacks on modular exponentiation, but those are as much a problem for OAEP as for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. They also rely on the attacker gaining more knowledge from the system than should be allowed for a secure system to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure this oracle you're talking about is not available to an attacker is a bit harder than just saying so.

When we first heard of the Vaudenay attack on CBC (https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2002/23320530/cbc02_e02d.pdf) we thought that we had done enough to "get rid of the oracle" and we found out with the Lucky13 attack (http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/tls/Lucky13.html) that it wasn't so.

What will be the reaction of a recipient when he gets a badly formatted ciphertext ?

If his responses are indistinguishable but the timing of said responses varies this is bad too.

I would also like to point out that Bleichenbacher attack was improved by the Crypto 2012 paper of Bardou et al (https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/417.pdf)